# Native RSS reader which allows to set explizit the status of an article

Tags: rss

I am looking for a native RSS reader for Mac OS which allows me to mark an article as read or unread explicitly by a short cut. All RSS reader I found mark an article as read immediately after viewing them. So I lose the overview which articles I have read and which not.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your answers. After trying different web-based tools and native applications I returned to [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/). Thunderbird supports RSS-Feeds as well and allows you to specify the amount of time you have to view a mail or article until it marks it as read. It also allows you to disable this at all and to mark articles manually as read.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but I think [Yoleo](https://yoleoreader.com/) might have the ability to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  [Feedly](http://www.feedly.com)?

Many options as to marking / keeping Read articles.

Nice on the web too - they have a Safari extension.